# Generic with multiple classes

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters

I'm trying to create this generic method to simplify things but I think I messed it up! Can you help with my problem?

This compiles:

```
private string ConcatenateText<T1, T2>(MyEntity myEntity) 
    where T1 : Supplier, new()
    where T1 : Employee, new()
    where T2 : SupplierDepartment, new()
    where T2 : EmployeeDepartment, new()
{
    T1 p = new T1();
    T2 r = new T2();
    //Code here for myEntity treatment
    return mystring;
}
```

While this does not compile:

```
protected void mybutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string mystring = ConcatenaText<Supplier, SupplierDepartment>(myEntity);
}

//This does not compile
protected void mybutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string mystring = ConcatenaText<Employee, EmployeeDepartment>(myEntity);
}
```

**Message: The type Supplier cannot be used as type parameter T1 in the generic type or method ConcatenateText(MyEntity myEntity). There is no implicit reference conversion from Supplier to Employee**

Can this be done? What am I doing wrong? Can it be improved?

**EDIT:**

And MyEntity is just another class in order to process it inside this generic method! It's not related to the types T. It just an argument. But it's clear that I can't do that, using 2 types like that. I thought that I could assign one or another and the CLR independently of my initialization could react as I wanted. I gonna accept the answer who share a little bit more information about it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First of all, your code that tries to set two type constraints on generic parameter `T1` does not compile

```
where T1 : Supplier, new()
where T1 : Employee, new()
```

with the following error:

> A constraint clause has already been specified for type parameter 'T1'. All of the constraints for a type parameter must be specified in a single where clause.

As MSDN article states you can use only one `where` constraint on each generic parameter (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

> "With multiple type parameters, use one where clause for each type parameter..."

You also cannot put multiple class names into one 'where' constraint. Only one class name and several interfaces.

```
where T1 : Supplier, IContractor, IComparable, new()
```

Keep in mind that this constraint dictates that the actual type you provide as the generic parameter `T1` must be a successor of the `Supplier` class or `Supplier` class itself AND it has to implement both `IContractor` AND `IComparable` interfaces.

As soon as your method accepts a `MyEntity` object and you do not specify what relation it has to `Employee` and `Supplier` classes, I cannot guess how this `MyEntity` class knows about `Employee` and `Supplier` classes and how this relation helps you.

The only thing I can suggest is either to create an interface or a base class and inherit both of your classes from it. This is the only good reason I see for creating a generic method. It could look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method1<Employee>();
        Method1<Supplier>();
    }

    private static void Method1<T1>()
        where T1 : IContractor, new()
    {

    }
}

public class Supplier : IContractor
{
    string IContractor.Name
    {
        get{return "Supplier-Mufflier";}
    }
}

public class Employee : IContractor
{
    string IContractor.Name
    {
        get{return "Employee-Merloyee";}
    }
}

public interface IContractor
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

If your classes Supplier and Employee do not have something important in common that is enough for creating a common interface they could implement then you should not make a generic method for processing them.

Create an overloaded method for each of such types.

Imagine you have two classes: `Wife` and `Wine`. Both have an attribute of `Age` and of the same type too. But do not even think of creating a common interface `IAged` for those classes. The essence of the classes and the meaning of the `Age` is so different that one should never unify them. Nevertheless some common logic might perfectly serve you. For example:

```
private double AgeQualify(Wife someWife)
{
    return 1 / (someWife.Age * someWife.Beachness);
}

private double AgeQualify(Wine someWine)
{
    return someWine.Age / someWine.Sugar;
}
```

Comment: oops, while I was writing my answer another two appeared and saying almost the same

Comment: Great answer but if i remembered correctly you cannot overload multiple classes on one class. So Interface and generic is a good alternative in this example.

Comment: @TarıkÖzgünGüner Do not mix up overload and override.

Answer (score 20):

You either need to make separate versions:

```
private string ConcatenateText<T1, T2>(MyEntity myEntity) 
    where T1 : Supplier, new()
    where T2 : SupplierDepartment, new()  
{
    T1 p = new T1();
    T2 r = new T2();
    return mystring;
}

private string ConcatenateText<T1, T2>(MyEntity myEntity) 
    where T1 : Employee, new()
    where T2 : EmployeeDepartment, new()
{
    T1 p = new T1();
    T2 r = new T2();
    return mystring;
}
```

or need to make them share a base class:

```
private string ConcatenateText<T1, T2>(MyEntity myEntity) 
    where T1 : EmployeeSuplierBase, new()
    where T2 : EmployeeSupplierDeparmentBase, new()
{
    T1 p = new T1();
    T2 r = new T2();
    return mystring;
}
```

I'd prefer the separate versions, really, because with them they can't call it with `Supplier` and `EmployeeDeparment` (or vice versa)

Comment: Seperate versions won't work. You have defined two methods with the same name and the same parameters. Unfortunately changing the return type does not make it overloadable.

Answer (score 2):

You really should not use generics in that case.
There are only two options.

So:

```
string ConcatenateText(Supplier Entity) { ...code...} 
string ConcatenateText(Employee Entity) { ...code...}
```

What you can do is unify both with a base class concentrating all common methods.

Say, if both supplier and employee has `Name`:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class Employee : BaseClass
{
    //emplyee stuff except name and other things already in base
}

class Supplier : BaseClass
{
    //supplier stuff except name and other things already in base
}
```

And then, the method takes `BaseClass`:

```
private string ConcatenateText(BaseClass Entity) 
{ 
    //code
}
```