# What alternative to more class constraints to same generic exists in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

Considering the following structure:

```
public class A
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static int Sum<T>(T template, int input) where T : A
    {
        return template.Prop + input;
    }
}
```

The sum of `Prop` and `input` can be computed, but only if generic `T` type is `A`.

Is there a way to make this method work for both `A` and `B` without changing the structure of classes?

(I know they can derive from the same base class/interface and define the generic as the base type, but I can't modify them). I have tried:

```
public static int Sum<T>(T template, int input) where T : A
                                                where T : B
{
    return template.Prop + input;
}
```

But this is not working and it generates:

> A constraint clause has already been specified for type parameter 'T'. All of the constraints for a type parameter must be specified in a single where clause.

**EDIT**

I am not necessary looking to have a generic parameter of type of two separate classes, but I am looking for a way the same functionality as of these two types assigned to a single parameter to be achieved.

Comment: Does it have to be limited to only A and B?

Comment: @Dandré yes, only `A` and `B`, these are the only constraints, but both are concrete classes.

Comment: Multiple constraints means 'AND', nor 'OR'. `T : A` and `T : B` would mean T extends both A and B. You cannot extend 2 classes.

Comment: You can write two methods `Sum`: one for `A` and another for `B`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov you have a good point, but this is the reason I want to specify that the concrete type is `A` or `B`, because I don't want to make duplicate code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic with multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814312/generic-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Generics imply a forall relationship on their type parameters, so it doesn't make sense to then try to enumerate the possible instantiations. C# supports that with overloading.

Comment: At the point at which it's compiling the `Sum` method and wants to generate the code for `template.Prop`, it's got to emit a metadata token that identifies the property to access. It only gets to emit one token, and that has to identify a *specific* property belonging to a *specific* type. Despite them sharing a name, the two properties in `A` and `B` are completely unrelated.

Comment: Would it be okay if the function sum throws an error when the parameter isn't a or b and the parameter is a dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using generics to begin with? Just use method overloading:

```
public static int Sum(A template, int input) { ... }

public static int Sum(B template, int input) { ... }
```

To avoid duplicate code, simply delegate implementation:

```
public static int Sum(A template, int input) { return add(A.Prop, input); }
public static int Sum(B template, int input) { return add(B.Prop, input); }
private static int add(int prop, int input) { ... }
```

Comment: Because the current example is in a nutshell the case I am actually facing. I will have a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: @meJustAndrew then simply delegate to a third method that implements the logic. See edits

Comment: This is a good approach, but I have a lot of properties with a few logic to compute them, so they will all be needed to sent through parameters of a method which will not be clean enough. I have to keep the logic inside the `Sum` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **wrapper** class:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private A a;
    private B b;        

    public Wrapper(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Wrapper(B b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int Prop { get { return (int)(a?.Prop ?? b?.Prop); } }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static int Sum(this Wrapper template, int input)
    {
        return template.Prop + input;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var a = new A();
var result = (new Wrapper(a)).Sum(2);
//or
var b = new B();
result = (new Wrapper(b)).Sum(2);
```

> There is another solution with the help of **explicit conversion**:

```
public class Wrapper
{        
    public Wrapper(int Prop)
    {
        this.Prop = Prop;
    }

    public static explicit operator Wrapper(A a)
    {
        return new Wrapper(a.Prop);
    }

    public static explicit operator Wrapper(B b)
    {
        return new Wrapper(b.Prop);
    }

    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

//Extension method still the same...
```

**Usage:**

```
var a = new A();
var result = ((Wrapper)a).Sum(2);
//or
var b = new B();
result = ((Wrapper)b).Sum(2);
```

Comment: This is completly new from all other approaches, still the answer to my question is that it is a duplicate and it isn't possible to reach a generic type to have multiple possible concrete classes.

Comment: I decided to un-mark this answer, because it need to duplicate the code in constructors... I am very sorry, but I just realized it when I was trying to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your post, the only way to reduce duplicate code is:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int Sum(A template, int input)
    {
        return Sum(template.Prop, input);
    }

    public static int Sum(B template, int input)
    {
        return Sum(template.Prop, input);
    }

    static int Sum(int templateProp, int input) 
    {
        return templateProp + input;
    }
}
```

This assuming you had more complex logic inside your methods.

Comment: But the first two methods are still duplicated code... Indeed, reduced!