# Why is it not possible to use generic type as follow classname<T<J>>

Tags: c#, generics, types

I cant get my head around why `classname<T<J>>` produce compile error. Is it not logical?

```
public class classname<T<J>>
{

}
```

Comment: Just try it out.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814312/generic-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: It will get compile time error

Answer (score 1):

What you are considering is *sensible*, but unfortunately this is *not yet* supported. It is called *higher kinded parametric polymorphism* a feature dearly awaited. [Roslyn issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339)

---

**P.S.** Just in case, you might want to consider something like the following,

```
public class A<T, J> where T : ISomething<J>
{

}
```