# Class type constraint must come before any other constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
private Panel formPanel<T>(T basePanel) where T : Class1, Class2
```

Class1 and class2 have some properties same and I want to access them. But error comes:

```
Class type constraint clsss2 must come before any other constraint
```

Comment: "Class1 and class2 have some properties same and I want to access them." then you will need 1 interface that states these properties and both types have to implement this interface. Then you can restrict `T` to this interface and access the properties.

Comment: The problem is that using `T : Class1, Class2` indicates the compiler that `T` has to inherit from both `Class1` and `Class2`. Multiple interitance is not allowed in C#. You can create an interface for all of the members you want to use, let `LineChartPanel` and `PieChartPanel` implement that interface. After that `T` can be restricted to that interface. This of course only works if you created the classes.

Comment: Closed - okay, but the link might not answer the question. OP does not want to inherit a new class from two given classes. OP tries to restrict a generic to one of the specified classes. Yes the syntax causes `T` to inherit from both - but that's why OP asked for help.

Comment: See [new duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814312/generic-with-multiple-classes). You need an interface or base class.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thx - that link is the correct one.